# Inserting a 30 million row table from a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have a large table that needs to be updated on a nightly basis from a linked server.  Initially I had simply truncated the table and inserted all of the records but this was taking too long.  I'm now using a merge statement to copy over only the records that need updating.  However this appears to still take too long, i.e. 10+ hours  What other methods or techniques can I use to get this table refreshed from the linked server on a daily basis?

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
MERGE dbo.[ANNOUNCEMENTS] AS Target
USING (SELECT [ANN_ID]
      ,[ANNOUNCEMENT]
      ,[SCH_OR_DIST_NUM]
      ,[START_DATE]
      ,[END_DATE]
      ,[CREATED_BY]
      ,[CREATION_DATE]
      ,[UPDATED_BY]
      ,[LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
    FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[ANNOUNCEMENTS]) 
            AS source ([ANN_ID]
                        ,[ANNOUNCEMENT]
                        ,[SCH_OR_DIST_NUM]
                        ,[START_DATE]
                        ,[END_DATE]
                        ,[CREATED_BY]
                        ,[CREATION_DATE]
                        ,[UPDATED_BY]
                        ,[LAST_UPDATE_DATE])
    ON (Target.ANN_ID = source.ANN_ID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ([ANN_ID]
              ,[ANNOUNCEMENT]
              ,[SCH_OR_DIST_NUM]
              ,[START_DATE]
              ,[END_DATE]
              ,[CREATED_BY]
              ,[CREATION_DATE]
              ,[UPDATED_BY]
              ,[LAST_UPDATE_DATE])
        VALUES (source.[ANN_ID]
              ,source.[ANNOUNCEMENT]
              ,source.[SCH_OR_DIST_NUM]
              ,source.[START_DATE]
              ,source.[END_DATE]
              ,source.[CREATED_BY]
              ,source.[CREATION_DATE]
              ,source.[UPDATED_BY]
              ,source.[LAST_UPDATE_DATE]);
END
```

Comment: Why not backup / restore, then you can at least perform the data move locally (or just create a view against the restored copy - even easier). As an aside, [I'd be very careful with `MERGE`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)...

Comment: If backing up isn't an option why not use SSIS? This looks like a perfect case for using an SSIS look-up/insert method. I can build you a demo if you'd like.

Comment: Unfortunately backing up is not an option.  I suppose I will work on the SSIS package to see if I can get better performance out of it.

Comment: Is there a clustered index on source creation_date? Why are you using the whole table as a source and not just where creation_date >= yesterday at midnight and < today at midnight? A simple INSERT with that where clause would be sufficient instead of MERGE.

Comment: Also, can you explain why `backing up is not an option` - are you not taking backups now? Living on the edge?

Comment: Another question what's the volume of nightly inserts?

Comment: @Aaron Backing up is not an option because I don't have the rights to perform backups and the server I'm pulling data from is a pass-through server to an Oracle database.  We are trying to move off Oracle and set up the pass-through server as a means of getting data from Oracle into SQL.  I've asked if I can just link directly to the Oracle but they don't want to install the Oracle drives on the destination server.  Therefore I don't think backing up a database which consists of views pointing to the Oracle server.  I know it's not the ideal setup but it's what I have to deal with.

Comment: @Zane I'm unsure of the volume of nightly inserts but I believe it's significant.

Comment: To be frank, what some people consider "significant" - even when they *know* the number - can be quite different from others. This is like big data, wicked fast, pretty tall, etc. Can you find out what percentage of the 30 million rows are new each day?

Comment: Or an average of your nightly inserts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MERGE` doesn't seem to be what you want here. You're only inserting new rows with a `CREATION_DATE` from the past 24 hours, right?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Yesterday DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE());

INSERT dbo.ANNOUNCEMENTS(column list)
SELECT column list
  FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[ANNOUNCEMENTS] AS r
  WHERE CREATION_DATE >= @Yesterday 
  AND CREATION_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Yesterday)
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ANNOUNCEMENTS WHERE ANN_ID = r.ANN_ID);
```

Of course having useful indexes on `CREATION_DATE` and/or `ANN_ID` will help.

Comment: I have other tables with the same problem but don't have an updated date field.  It seems like I cannot apply the answer to these columns: [STUDENT_ID]
    ,[SECTION_ID]
    ,[STUSEC_START_DATE]
    ,[STUSEC_END_DATE]
    ,[TERM_CODE]
    ,[ROOM_NUMBER]
    ,[BEGIN_PERIOD]
    ,[END_PERIOD]
    ,[SCHEDULE_NAME]
    ,[SCHOOL_NUMBER]
    ,[SCHOOL_NAME]
    ,[SASI_COURSE_CODE]
    ,[COURSE_TITLE]
    ,[CREDIT_HOURS]
    ,[INSTRUCT_LANGUAGE_CODE]
    ,[INSTRUCT_TYPE_CODE]
    ,[TEACHER_NAME]
    ,[TERM_CODE_SORT]
    ,[DPSID]
    ,[SCHOOL_YEAR]
    ,[SCHEDULE_STRUCTURE]
    ,[SECTION_NUMBER]

Comment: @Geoff if you need to restrict the rows to something less than the whole table, you'll need to add a new column so that you can filter that way. The above should still work (without the where clause of course), but it won't be any quicker than what you're doing now. The filter is the key.